# Node.js selenium webdriver incognito mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am having an hard time figuring out how to launch Selenium Webdriver for Chrome in incognito mode.

I understand I need to pass the `--incognito` parameter to chromedriver, but how do I do that when creating the driver instance?

This is how I am currently instantiating my driver object:

```
require("chromedriver");
const webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
const driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
```

Comment: random guess: `new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").setChromeOptions({args: ['--incognito']}).build();`... else this looks promising too: https://gist.github.com/anandsunderraman/e351485319a8a0e7df7e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/anandsunderraman/e351485319a8a0e7df7e) by the github user anandsunderraman helped me solving the problem in Node.js:

```
// import the selenium web driver
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

// create chrome capabilities
var chromeCapabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();

// add the desired options
var chromeOptions = {'args': ['--test-type', '--incognito']};
chromeCapabilities.set('chromeOptions', chromeOptions);

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities).build();
```

Comment: FYI, for anyone trying to use 4.0.0-alpha.5 of Selenium Web Driver, the above does not work.  You will need to use version 3.6.0.

Comment: If you're using selenium 4, use goo:chromeOptions instead of chromeOptions to set the capabilities.

chromeCapabilities.set("goog:chromeOptions", chromeOptions);

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `--incognito` to your `ChromeOptions` or `DesiredCapabilities`.

I don't use node.js, but judging by the [README.md](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/README.md) from the Selenium GitHub it should look like this:

```
var options = new chrome.Options();
options.addArguments("--incognito");
const driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").setChromeOptions(options).build();
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer has been useful in directing me to the actual Node.js solution